# How to define global function in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to define a function to be global from within a class( or from within another function, as matter of fact)? Something similar to defining a global variable.

Comment: Why would you want to do that at all?

Comment: You can assign a global variable a function defined locally, if that's what you mean

Comment: I imagine you could use `global foo` and `def`/`class foo` to do this...

Comment: @flamenco: Functions are objects.  They can already be returned and passed as parameters just like anything else.

Comment: I venture to propose a concrete use case for this: dynamical redefinition of functions aliases, based on user input. Eg, let's say you use `bytearray()` for optimization purposes, because all your values are assumed to be within 0 and 255. Now let's say that you want to support values above 255 in some cases, but you want to get maximum performance for cases when values are guaranteed to be bounded to 0..255. One way to do that is at `my_setup_function()` to redefine `bytearray` dynamically to a `list()` if needed.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this was downvoted? I think it's a very valid question, I've just come across this issue myself.

Comment: @Eddy: There are numerous valid reasons to do this (e.g., non-premature optimization as [highlighted by @gaborous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930038/how-to-define-global-function-in-python#comment56715423_27930038)). Sadly, some Pythonistas believe that their personal failure to conceive of a valid use case for a requested solution implies *all* possible solutions to be harmful. **See also:** the snark radiating from [Martijn Pieters'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) comment above.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Functions are added to the current namespace like any other name would be added. That means you can use the `global` keyword inside a function or method:

```
def create_global_function():
    global foo
    def foo(): return 'bar'
```

The same applies to a class body or method:

```
class ClassWithGlobalFunction:
    global spam
    def spam(): return 'eggs'

    def method(self):
        global monty
        def monty(): return 'python'
```

with the difference that `spam` will be defined immediately as top-level class bodies are executed on import.

Like all uses of `global` you probably want to rethink the problem and find another way to solve it. You could *return* the function so created instead, for example.

Demo:

```
>>> def create_global_function():
...     global foo
...     def foo(): return 'bar'
... 
>>> foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
>>> create_global_function()
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x102a0c7d0>
>>> foo()
'bar'
>>> class ClassWithGlobalFunction:
...     global spam
...     def spam(): return 'eggs'
...     def method(self):
...         global monty
...         def monty(): return 'python'
... 
>>> spam
<function spam at 0x102a0cb18>
>>> spam()
'eggs'
>>> monty
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'monty' is not defined
>>> ClassWithGlobalFunction().method()
>>> monty()
'python'
```

Comment: @flamenco: I was indeed assuming that the OP meant *from a method on a class*. Not from the class body itself. In any case, the same applies to using the statement in a `class` definition body, but I'd be rather pushed as to *why you'd want to do that*.

Comment: @flamenco: The code in my previous answer clearly explains that you don't  a wrapper function.

Comment: @flamenco: altering globals is not thread-safe and can easily lead to *very* confusing code. Altering functions this way even more so.

Answer (score 10):

You can use global to declare a global function from within a class. The problem with doing that is you can not use it with a class scope so might as well declare it outside the class.

```
class X:
  global d
  def d():
    print 'I might be defined in a class, but I\'m global'

>> X.d

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   AttributeError: 'X' object has no attribute 'd'

>> d()

I might be defined in a class, but I'm global
```

Comment: So I haven't posted more than 4 times in stackoverflow. Big deal? The answer nonetheless does explain to you how to get this done and a native problem associated with the question.

Comment: outside the class is like breaking the encapsulation principle of OOPS. However the method declared as global can be called by other methods within the class but on a any object of the class. In which case the 'global'word really does not makes sense. Its more local (private in java terms) than global as only the class methods can access this method declared as global. This all sounds messy naming convention is this specif scenario. I believe this aspect needs rectification in python

Answer (score 4):

I found a case where global does not have the desired effect: inside .pdbrc file. If you define functions in .pdbrc they will only be available from the stack frame from which pdb.set_trace() was called.

However, you can add a function globally, so that it will be available in all stack frames, by using an alternative syntax:

```
def cow(): print("I'm a cow")
globals()['cow']=cow
```

I've tested that it also works in place of the global keyword in at least the simplest case:

```
def fish():
    def cow(): 
        print("I'm a cow")
    globals()['cow']=cow
```

Despite being more verbose, I thought it was worth sharing this alternative syntax. I have not tested it extensively so I can't comment on its limitations vs using the global keyword.